# Licensing subcomponents

Tags: licensing, gpl

Say I produce system X, which contains some components (A, B and C, say) which are specific to X, but ripe for generalisation. Let's say X is licensed with a viral open source license ([AL]?GPL).

If I decide to break any of A, B or C out as standalone systems, under their own distribution, can they be relicensed, or do they need to keep the same license as X? e.g., Can A be MIT, or BSD, etc.? The code of A, B and C is nearly identical to that as source in X; but even significant changes would still be clear derivatives of X. Does the "virusness" of X's license preclude any use of a more permissive license on after-the-fact components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on who contributed to the system *X*.

#### Case 1: You did it all by yourself

You are the sole copyright owner of system *X*. You have decided to distribute that code under a viral open source license. You may at any point stop offering the system under such a license, although you can't cancel existing *GPL licenses or prevent other people from continuing to distribute the system under the original *GPL license. You may also additionally license the system in whole or in part under a different license, and let people choose which license they'd want to use. Dual-licensed software is a fairly frequent occurrence, and you may also transition to a dual-license “after the fact”. Provided again that you are the sole copyright owner.

#### Case 2: Other people contributed to the system

Let's say you put the *GPL-licensed code on GitHub, and you merged a pull request from someone who fixed a few bugs throughout the code. Since these changes where presumably provided to you under the *GPL license, the complete system is under shared copyright by you and all other contributors. Since everyone licensed their contributions under the *GPL, you are bound by this license, and relicensing the code in an incompatible manner is not permitted.

To change the license or to dual-license the code, you would either have to make all contributors accept a *contributor license agreement* before their changes are merged into a project, which is usually a copyright assignment to you so that you maintain full control over the code. Or you can contact all contributors after the fact and ask for their written permission to distribute the code under an incompatible license. However, nobody is required to give such permission and without such permission from every single contributor you cannot proceed.

#### Relicensing only certain components of the system

You are free to split up a system *X* into components *A*, *B*, *C*, but all those components will retain their original *GPL license. For each of these components you can then try to separately relicense or dual-license them as outlined above. In particular this means that when you are trying to relicense a component *C*, you don't have to ask contributors that didn't contribute to *C* for permission.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are the only programmer of A, you can relicense component A in any way as you like. Otherwise, you have to ask all contributers, if they are OK with relicensing.

Comment: is this merely your opinion or you can back it up somehow?